# How do I properly delete a join instance from many-to-many in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have three classes: PeelTestFile, DiscreteJob and PeelTestFileJob. This is a similar setup to the User,Group and UserGroup classic problem. I'm trying to delete a PeelTestFileJob. When I do so, it is setting the foreign keys to null. This is a problem because I have the foreign keys set to NOT NULL, which is proper. I want it to just remove the one record in the database, and then in Java I want it to remove the instance from the two sets to which it belongs (this is where it seems to be setting the null).

Below is my code. What's the proper way to do this?

```
public class DiscreteJob
{
  private Set<PeelTestFileJob>            peelTestJobs;

  /**
   * @hibernate.set
   *   inverse="true"
   *   lazy="true"
   *   cascade="all-delete-orphan"
   * @hibernate.collection-key
   *   column="WIP_ENTITY_ID"
   * @hibernate.collection-one-to-many
   *   class="com.icumed.ifactory3.dto.PeelTestFileJob"
   */
  public Set<PeelTestFileJob> getPeelTestJobs()
  {
    return this.peelTestJobs;
  }

  public boolean remove(
    PeelTestFileJob peelTestFileJob)
  {
    return this.peelTestJobs.remove(peelTestFileJob);
  }

  public void setPeelTestJobs(
    Set<PeelTestFileJob> peelTestJobs)
  {
    this.peelTestJobs = peelTestJobs;
  }
}

public class PeelTestFile
{
  private Set<PeelTestFileJob>   peelTestFileJobs;

  /**
   * @hibernate.set 
   *   inverse="true"
   *   lazy="true"
   *   cascade="all-delete-orphan"
   * @hibernate.collection-key
   *   column="PEEL_TEST_FILE_ID" 
   * @hibernate.collection-one-to-many
   *   class="com.icumed.ifactory3.dto.PeelTestFileJob"
   */
  public Set<PeelTestFileJob> getPeelTestFileJobs()
  {
    return this.peelTestFileJobs;
  }

  public boolean remove(
    PeelTestFileJob peelTestFileJob)
  {
    return this.peelTestFileJobs.remove(peelTestFileJob);
  }

  public void setPeelTestFileJobs(
    Set<PeelTestFileJob> jobs)
  {
    this.peelTestFileJobs = jobs;
  }
}

public class PeelTestFileJob
{
  private PeelTestFile      peelTestFile;
  private DiscreteJob       job;
  private User              createdBy;
  private Date              creationDate;

  /**
   * @hibernate.many-to-one
   *   column="PEEL_TEST_FILE_ID"
   *   not-null="true"
   *   outer-join="false"
   */
  public PeelTestFile getPeelTestFile()
  {
    return this.peelTestFile;
  }

  public void setPeelTestFile(
    PeelTestFile file)
  {
    this.peelTestFile = file;
  }

  /**
   * @hibernate.many-to-one
   *   column="WIP_ENTITY_ID"
   *   not-null="true"
   *   outer-join="false"
   */
  public DiscreteJob getJob()
  {
    return this.job;
  }

  public void setJob(
    DiscreteJob job)
  {
    this.job = job;
  }
}
```

Below is my code that's causing the problem:

```
super.getHibernateTemplate().delete(peelTestFileJob);

if (job.remove(peelTestFileJob)) // setting foreign key to null?
{
  if (peelTestFile.remove(peelTestFileJob)) // setting foreign key to null?
  {
    if (peelTestFile.getPeelTestFileJobs().isEmpty())
    {
      // modify the peel test file here

      getPeelTestFileDAO().update(peelTestFile, bioIdentification);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have 2 entity class + 1 automatically created table for many to many relationship. and the reason of why your FK data became null because you use set of your relationship table (`Set<PeelTestFileJob>`) instead of set of DiscreteJob or PeelTestFile.

entity class example to join table A many to many table B (in your case DiscreteJob with PeelTestFile):

in table A:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinTable(name="A_JOIN_B",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="A_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="B_ID")})
private Set<TestTableB> testJoins = new HashSet<TestTableB>();
```

in table B:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="testJoins")
private Set<TestTableA> testJoins = new HashSet<TestTableA>();
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___*EDIT****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
I test this and this is work :

the key is to use `@OneToMany(mappedBy="bId", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)` bId is FK in join table entity. and try to delete your inverse = true if you dont need it.
[inverse: If true, Hibernate will not try to insert or update the properties defined by this join. Default to false.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html)

this is parent table example(like PeelTestFile or DiscreteJob  in your case) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_TABLE_B")
public class TestTableB {

    //constructors here

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "B_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "B_NAME")
    private String bName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="bId", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    private Set<AJoinB> testJoins = new HashSet<AJoinB>();
    //getters and setters here
```

this A join B table example (in your case PeelTestFileJob):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A_JOIN_B")
public class AJoinB {
    //constructors here

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "C_NAME")
    private String aName;
    //you can add another column here

    @Column(name = "A_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long aId;

    @Column(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long bId;
    //getter setters here
```

when i do this command in java i delete 1 row in A join B table:

```
TestTableB b = (TestTableB) this.genericDao.getList("from TestTableB b where b.id = 1",false,null).get(0);
Set<AJoinB> testJoins = b.getTestJoins();
AJoinB ab = (AJoinB) testJoins.toArray()[0];
this.genericDao.remove(ab);
```

Comment: I need that table and that class because there's additional information besides the join data. There's also these columns: created_by, creation_date, last_updated_by, last_update_date.

Comment: edited so you can keep other column inside the join table, i thing the main difference is in the **inverse** and **cascade** property

Comment: I finally have time to come back to this. The problem I am having right now is that after the call to "this.genericDao.remove(ab)", I need to call "b.getTestJoins().remove(ab)" because I'm going back to a web page that will show b and Set<AJoinB>. At that time, while I'm in the same session, and now committing the transaction, that Hibernate tries to set A_JOIN_B.B_ID = null, which causes a problem since B_ID is not nullable.

Comment: plus, since I'm using XDoclet, I don't have cascade=DETACH

Comment: you say **after the call to "this.genericDao.remove(ab)", I need to call "b.getTestJoins().remove(ab)"** why did you try to remove same object twice? if you can't add `cascade` option, `.remove(ab)` should remove one row in the join table.

Comment: Because on the Java side, I need to remove it from the Set. Just deleting the record from the join table does not seem to remove it from the Java Set b.getTestJoins(). I need that element removed from the set because I use the "b" instance in the next web page. I also need to update the a.getTestJoins() set.

Comment: So these are the three goals I am trying to accomplish: 
1) delete the row from the join table 
2) b.getTestJoins().remove(ab) to clean up Java set 
3) a.getTestJoins().remove(ab) to clean up Java set

Comment: where did you think `set<AJoinB>` stored? in table A_JOIN_B ofcourse. so if you delete 1 record in AJoinB(`AJoinB.genericDao.remove(ab)` then save and commit), and you query table A or B did you think `set<AJoinB>` in the A or B still have the same size as before?

Comment: I do not re-query A or B. After I delete AJoinB, I want Set<AJoinB> to have one less element without going back to the database. That's why I was calling remove().